# Double Click of the browser back button not working

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, url-routing

Is there a way that I can detect and stop the double click of the browser back button?

Right now I have a scenario where, I am using Backbone.js for routing aspects. When the user clicks the browser back button, it routes to the proper url/page. Whereas , if he double clicks, the session expires.

Can anybody throw some light on this. All so it must be noted that the page reload even on double click shows the user session as logged in(correct behaviour)

Comment: What browser are you having this issue with?

Comment: I am currently working with Chrome. But I want a generic bit of explanation/code to be able to do it across cross browsers(baring the age old ie8  and less)

Comment: The problem I am facing with is that when I check the code in the normal flow, the routing is working fine. But once the double click has been made, the session shows as expired. Although it is not the case

Comment: Can you put up a fiddle that replicates the problem?

Comment: Its hard to do that. Reason being, its happening on a live website of my company and I am not supposed to share any code bits as per my policy